# Что означает такая форма записи в C#?

Tags: c#, byte

Вот код

```cs
short x = 150;

byte y = (byte)(x + x);
```

Вопрос конкретно о значении byte y и (byte)(x+x). Что вообще byte значит? Что в математическом смысле значит (byte)(x+x)? Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Типы `short` и `byte` — целочисленные типы из C#. Короткое целое со знаком `short` может хранить целые от -32768 до 32767. В нём 16 битов, один из которых хранит знак. Байт состоит из 8 битов и не содержат знака, поэтому в нём могут храниться значения от 0 до 255.

Пример демонстрирует особенности явного приведения типа и возможную потерю данных.

Поскольку `x` равно 150, `x + x` равно 300. Это значение не может поместиться в байт, поэтому старшие 8 бит отбрасываются. Результатом будет число 300 по модулю 256, то есть 300 % 256, то есть 44.

Поскольку здесь возникает потеря данных (отбрасывание лишних бит), компилятор C# не выполняет приведение типа автоматически, мы явно должны привести тип с помощью конструкции `(byte)`.

Если потеря данных не возникает, обычно есть неявное преобразование, например из `byte` в `short` приводить значения не обязательно.

Answer (score 0):

[`byte`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.byte?view=net-7.0) - это тип, представляющий 8 битное число без знака. Диапазон значений от 0 до 255

Запись `(byte)x` - называется [явным приведением типов](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions#explicit-conversions). Значение переменной будет приведено к типу `byte`.